# Reversing string using stack (static array) in c++

Tags: c++, stack

i am new to this concept in c++
i am trying to reverse string using stack static array implementation in c++.
Input: qwerty
expected output: ytrewq
output which i am getting is: trewq
Can some one explain me why is this happening and any possible solution.
Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define SIZE 10

string arr[SIZE];
unsigned a = -1;

void push(char ch) {
    a = a + 1;
    arr[a] = ch;
}

void pop() {
    a = a - 1;
}

void display() {
    for (int j = a; j >= 0; j--)
        cout << arr[j];
}

int main() {
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
        for (int i = 0; i < (str.length() - 1); i++)
            push(str[i]);
        display();
}
```

Comment: 1) Did you try stepping through your code, with a debugger, while looking over the values of variables, at each execution step? 2) Off topic: your `try`/`catch` block has no purpose, since nothing in your code ever `throw`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "-1" in :

```
for(int i=0;i<(str.length())-1;i++)
```

Else your array doesn't contains the last character.
I made the test without the -1,  it works well. 
The condition "< str.length()" is enough to loop on all string caracter.

In similar case, use the debugger to see what contains your variable. In these case the variable "arr" don't contains the last input caracter.

Answer (score 1):

You push everything on the stack, so the last element can be popped first. Then do popping to fill a reversed strng. The stack should be a char array.

As this is typically a task, the rest is your puzzle.

---

Pop typically gives you the top element as:

```
char pop() {
    char ch = arr[a];
    --a;
    return ch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to reverse a string would be to do:

```
std::reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
```

But I think this might be homework/study so look at your output. You are just missing the last letter. That suggests the upper limit of your loop is wrong doesn't it?